# How can I reset object every time a function is called in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I've found the solution.  I needed to copy the object with

```
var afcUpdate = structuredClone(arsenal)
```

Original did

```
var afcUpdate = arsenal
```

which linked the two so changes to afcUpdate also change arsenal.

Thanks to those who read and helped.

I have an object, and I want to update the object with user inputs.

If the user changes their inputs these should update the original object, my code is keeping the values stored in the updated object and adding to them.

I expect afcUpdate to be reset to the same as arsenal at the start of the function.
So that no matter how many times you click update, foo could never be more than 2 and bar could never be more that 3.

But, the afcUpdate isn't resetting to the same as the arsenal object at the start of the function, so if the user keeps clicking update the values will keep increasing.

Edit:  Got my actual code here now.  It's still a very basic version, I want to get the script to work before adding more 'selections'.

```js
const arsenal = {
  name: "Arsenal",
  played: 19,
  wins: 16,
  draws: 2,
  gd: 29,
};

document.querySelector('#update').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var afcUpdate = arsenal;
  var e = document.getElementById("as");
  var as = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var e = document.getElementById("ao");
  var ao = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if (as > ao) {
    afcUpdate.wins++
  }
  if (as == ao) {
    afcUpdate.draws++
  }

  afcUpdate.gd = afcUpdate + as - ao;
  document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = ((afcUpdate.wins * 3) + afcUpdate.draws);

})
```

```html
who will win the league

<div class="game">
  Arsenal
  
  <select id="as">
    <option value=1>0</option>
    <option value=2>1</option>
    <option value=3>2</option>
    <option value=4>3</option>
    <option value=5>4</option>
    <option value=6>5</option>
    <option value=7>6</option>
    <option value=8>7</option>
    <option value=9>8</option>
    <option value=1 0>9</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="ao">
    <option value=1>0</option>
    <option value=2>1</option>
    <option value=3>2</option>
    <option value=4>3</option>
    <option value=5>4</option>
    <option value=6>5</option>
    <option value=7>6</option>
    <option value=8>7</option>
    <option value=9>8</option>
    <option value=1 0>9</option>
  </select>
  
  Everton
</div>

<button id="update">Update Table</button>

<p id="feedback2"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot equality when defining your object `const object = foo:1, bar: 2 }`

Comment: also why `var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` are you just trying to get the values of your input? that keeps throwing undefined for me, unless there is some missing code that I'm not seeing. Also there is no condition anywhere that tells your code that foo could never be more than 2 and bar never more than 3

Comment: the equailty in when defining the object was just a mistake typing here, it was in the original code.

With `var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` honestly, like I said pretty new, that came from a webpage or something and that is what worked for me.

About the condition, the point is that I shouldn't need one.  The code can only add 1, and if anything is changed then foo should be reset to the original object.

Comment: Please take a closer look at how to edit the demo snippet. You had all the code in the JavaScript panel. Also, you have several extra closing div tags.